# Specific jupyter notebook config file for a virtual environment

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, python-venv

I created a virtual environment in python3 (with venv) to use several packages, including jupyter notebook.

Running the bash command `jupyter --config-dir` I noticed that the config file used by jupyter notebook in the virtual environment is the main one of my machine (`~/.jupyter/jupyter_notebook_config.py`).

How can I create a new config file and tell the virtual environment to use it. The goal is not to modify the main one because I need it for other projects.

Answer (score 5):

from https://jupyter.readthedocs.io/en/latest/use/jupyter-directories.html:

```
Config files are stored by default in the ~/.jupyter directory.

JUPYTER_CONFIG_DIR

    Set this environment variable to use a particular directory, other than the default, for Jupyter config files.
```

So what you'd need to do is set the `JUPYTER_CONFIG_DIR` environment variable when activating the environment.

How you do this depends on what virtual environment manager you're using. I believe with `venv` you should be able to add

```
export JUPYTER_CONFIG_DIR=/your/custom/config/dir
```

to the `activate` script that runs when you activate your virtual environment (should be in `$venv/environmentname/bin/activate`).

Another option that you might prefer (which is the route I went for this since I'm using pyenv+virtualenv, which does not use the `activate` script), you can use an additional tool like [direnv](https://github.com/direnv/direnv#direnv----unclutter-your-profile) or [dotenv](https://pypi.org/project/python-dotenv/) to set environment variables by project. In the case of direnv (which is a little simpler IMO), you create a `.envrc` file in your project directory with the `export` command from above, and then every time you `cd` into your project directory it runs the commands in the `.envrc` file. This works well if your virtual environments are organized by project.

Once the `JUPYTER_CONFIG_DIR` environment variable is being set properly, after your environment activates when you run `jupyter notebook --generate-config` it should create a new config file in the new directory.